# How to set specific size to UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I got a weird bug going on. I'm trying to programatically initialize an UIImageView with a specific frame and image. My image is 60x60, but I'm trying to resize it to 30x30 on the screen, which seems impossible.

The following works, but show the image in 60x60:

```
 UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
    [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
//    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 30, 30);
    imgView.center = CGPointMake(pointTouch.x, pointTouch.y);
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

And the following just doesn't show anything at all on the screen:

```
  UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
    [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 30, 30);
    imgView.center = CGPointMake(pointTouch.x, pointTouch.y);
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

What's wrong?

**EDIT**: **for those having the same problem, here is the working code:**

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2, 30, 30);
imgView.center = CGPointMake(pointTouch.x, pointTouch.y);
[imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: if you don't change `imgView.center`, does it show?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @gWiz: no, doesn't work either

Comment: @ErikKerber: No, I'm not

Comment: @AnthonyGuay Try setting imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor], rule out the image not being found.  Also, quadruple check that the view you are adding your UIImageView does not have the auto-layout checkbox checked (assuming it's in a storyboard or Nib). If auto layout is turned on, setting the frame will not have any impact.

Comment: @ErikKerber

Doesn't work either.. 

Auto Layout is disabled for all the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start experiment with

```
imgView.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.x/2, view.bounds.y/2);
imgView.bounds = view.bounds;
```

and see if this fills the superview. Then try `CGPointMake(pointTouch.x, pointTouch.y)` and `CGPointMake(30,30)` respectively.

I'm guessing this behaviour has something to do with **[warning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) about `frame`**:

> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You could try initializing the `UIImageView` with a set frame, then setting the image after that:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 30, 30)];
[imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
imgView.center = CGPointMake(pointTouch.x, pointTouch.y);
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Even if I remove the line imgView.center = CGPointMake(pointTouch.x, pointTouch.y);    , nothing gets added on the screen